# How to make this GestureDetector recognize taps?

Tags: flutter

I have a Card (containing some usual columns and rows with text) wrapped in a GestureDetector like below. The whole projectBoxContainer is wrapped in a `Wrap`, and then in a `SingleChildScrollview`.

```
 Widget projectBoxContainer(Project project, bool posted) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            print('project cliked!');
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return SingleProjectPage(project: project);
            }));
          },
          child: Card(
              child: SizedBox(
            
                  width: 280,
                  height: 100,
                  child: projectBoxContent(project, posted))),
        );
      }



  Widget projectBoxContent(Project project, bool posted) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(project.projectId,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't react to tapping at all. Things tried:

- changing GestureDetector to InkWell (no effect)
- removing both ScrollView and Wrap (no effect)
- wrapping the GestureDetector in a colored Container to see the area (Container doesn't display)
- adding various behaviours to the GD (no effect)

Something must be wrong with the code - any ideas?

Comment: you must share `projectBoxContent`, if you replace it with `SizedBox(height: 100)` everything works

Comment: Done - please see.

Comment: i test your code, and works perfect!

Comment: Always good to get a second pair of eyes. If the code was fine then it appeared impossible. So I examined one more time -  turns out, while I was generating these boxes twice with different parameters (on purpose) I somehow only added the GestureDetector to the other batch so the one in question didn't have it at all. :facepalm: - stupid. Thanks for checking!